# HttpClient on Silverlight with generic GET/POST methods?

Tags: c#, silverlight, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm going to consume some REST services from Silverlight client.

I saw [HTTP Client](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) which has a good usage of TPL, but I don't like that result type is just HttpResponseMessage

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string requestUri)
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content)
```

What I'd like to have is

```
public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string requestUri)
public Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string requestUri, object request)
```

to allow for automatic serialization/deserialization of requests and responses.
It doesn't seem difficult to write this kind of wrapper from scratch, but I'd better use an existing implementations, if any.

Is there something for that? If no, then maybe there's something wrong with that approach?